# I got 404 after page refresh inside routes on React + Vite app after deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, vite

So the problem is simple. After deploying my project to Railway i got 404 page after refresh inside my application. If i refreshing on home page everything ok, but after i do it inside the app (like /about) my app return 404 page.

The essence of the problem is that the server has no idea about the routes because all routing is only on client side.

I already research this problem, like cheking some other questions on stack overflow and googling it
[This one on the internet](https://ui.dev/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh)
[And this one on the stack overflow](https://ui.dev/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh)

Inside upper links there is some solutions, оne solution involves using Webpack and tweaking its configuration file a bit.
Something like that

```
devServer: {
   historyApiFallback: true,
   contentBase: './',
   hot: true
},
```

But there is a problem, since i use Vite, i didn't find information about how to configure Vite to works that way.

I read [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html) and maybe this is it, but I'm not sure if this is the solution to my problem.

Is it even possible to solve this problem using Vite, or do I need to completely migrate my app to Webpack?
Maybe I'm wrong and it's not even Vite's problem, but Railway's.
So, I am confused, if you have faced this problem and have a solution, please help

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: Any solutions? i am getting same on my project when deployed to railway

Comment: Any solutions found?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're using vite as the actual server (I don't think it's recommended), but have you tried adding appType to your `vite.config.js`? It worked well for me locally.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  appType: 'spa'
})
```

I didn't really find it in the docs anywhere but digging into the typefiles this looks like it might work.

I also found that adding `--debug` to see what happened with the routing when running locally was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be related with your `vite.config.ts` file.
In the generated index.html file, in your build output folder check the scripts & links source file and make sure the paths are absolute `/` and not relative `./`.

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-cdf274f4.js"></script>
<link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/assets/vendor-830d2326.js">
```

The reason why they are generated relative is due to `vite.config.ts` misconfiguration. Check your `vite.config.ts` and make sure that the there is nothing configured for `base` property.

See:
https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base